# Laravel 5 eloquent model auto add an underscore

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using laravel 5 for my small project and it seems like i'm having a problem with my model.

I have created this as my Model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class tOrders extends Model
{
    //
}
```

and this code from my controller to retrieve the data :

```
$test = tOrders::where('f_bank','=','ICBC')->orderBy('f_bank','ASC')->limit(10)->get();
```

after running the application, an error message came out saying

```
Invalid object name 't_orders'
```

i wonder where t_orders came from since my model is tOrders

Comment: I know this is off topic for this question, but it seems like you have a working integration with ICBC? Could you point me to where you got it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model name should start with an uppercase letter and your file name should be the same. And I suspect Laravel is picking your model name as t_orders because your model name is starting with a lowercase letter. However, in your case for example, your filename should be `Torders.php` and code should be:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Torders extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: great! that works! btw, is it possible to disable the underscore in laravel?

Comment: I don't think so, but not 100% sure. @kevin_marcus

Comment: Yes, you can. You can override the default table name by adding this to your model: `protected $table = 'your_table_name';`

Comment: @ThomasKim bro your answer makes sense also. thank you!

Comment: @ThomasKim is absolutely right but in that case you're telling your model to use that particular table. However the question was about changing the default Laravel's Model name parsing behaviour and I don't think so it is possible however you can always associate any table with this model by explicitly defining its name.

Comment: if you really wanted to do that you could override `getTable` on the model.